how would the database looks like if user can't make an account until admin allow him to?
I'm encountering a problem with my database design.
In my application, an employee (admin) is responsible for initializing a driving license by entering the ID, full name, and email of the license owner. After the driving license has been initialized, the owner can create an account on the app by selecting a username and password. However, the owner cannot create an account unless the employee has already initialized their driving license.
How should I structure this in my database design?
This is my current approach :
erd_design
Is there a better way to do it?
